# Neo4j2 and Rexster?

Tags: neo4j, rexster

This feels like a really basic, stupid question.

I've got a graph in Neo4j 2.1.5.  It's a toy graph, so it was created with the defaults.

I built the Neo4j2 version of Blueprints, as instructed.  I can get Rexster to start with this configuration:

```
<graph>
            <graph-name>graph.db</graph-name>
            <graph-type>com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j2.rexster.Neo4j2GraphConfiguration</graph-type>
            <graph-location>/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.5/libexec/data</graph-location>
            <properties>
              ...
         </properties>
        <extensions>
            <allows>
                <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
            </allows>
        </extensions>
    </graph>
```

When I open the Rexster web interface, it says the graph is there, but when I try to browse it, no dice.   I have no trouble browsing my graph from the Neo4j web interface.  What am I missing?

Comment: What happens when you try to browse it?  Can you elaborate on any errors you see? Does the REST API work?  in other words, what happens when you resolve: http://localhost:8182/graphs/graph.db - does that return anything?

Comment: When I try to browse, no nodes or relationships show up in the Rexster browser.  localhost:8182/graphs/graph.db resolves, but it appears to be empty.  If I use the Neo4j web interface (localhost:7474), everything is there.  From further web searching, it seems to be because I'm running Neo4j in server mode - my graph is expected to be too big for embedded (and ultimately we are planning to switch to Titan, but that's a whole 'nother set of problems).

Comment: that's probably right - you can't run server mode and embedded mode together without the `Neo4jHaGraph` instance.  If this was your problem I would have expected that Rexster's console/logs had some error messages in it pertaining to locking problems with neo4j.

Comment: There is no "too big for embedded" as Neo4j server and embedded use the same engine, the former only with web-ui and http-apis. What is the size of your graph? And are you sure this is the right location? `/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.5/libexec/data` is there no `graph.db` subdirectory?